# I tried to write a random response bot with pycharm in discord it did work, but there was one small problem

Tags: python, discord, bots

the problem is if you says the requested word but with an additional letter, word or phrase it just ignores it.

in pycharm I created 3 files but the most important was the random response one here is the code for the random response:

def get_response(message: str) -> str:
p_message = message.lower()

```
if p_message == '@Madrid':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if message == '@madridddsta':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if p_message == 'madridddsta#7819':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if p_message == '<@949798747586584647>':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if p_message == '@XTREditz':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if message == '@XTREditz#6250':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'

if p_message == '<@841488565225390080>':
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even close to understand what you're trying to do. As far as I got, seems you're checking if a string equals to another, while you're wanting to check if a string is inside another one. So for example:

```py
# Instead of this ❌
if message == '@madridddsta':
    # ...

# Try this! ✔️
if '@madridddsta' in message:
    # ...
```

Comment: im gonna try to explain it in a more understandable way:so basically you know that mario discord  bot that when u say something like "hello" he says "hello" , etc? thanks for the code I will try it.

Comment: edit:Big thanks! I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

import re

def get_response(message: str) -> str:
p_message = message.lower()

## match variations of the username

```
if re.search(r'@madrid+', p_message):
    return 'Reduce on pinging him, wait until he comes online and ask him what you wanted to ask.'
```

## match variations of the message text

```
if re.search(r'reduce on pinging him', p_message):
    return 'Please avoid excessive pinging, and wait for a response.'
```

## add a default response for messages that do not match any of the specific cases

```
return 'Sorry, I did not understand your message.'
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I already solved it, thanks for trying to help though!